# How to implement drag drop of html elements in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

If I would like to implement drag drop similar to JQuery with vuejs how would I do that ? How to move the elements in the DOM ?

I don't want to use a plugin I want to understand how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps look at the source to an [existing component](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable).

Comment: or this already to play examples list https://vuejsexamples.com/tag/drag/

Answer (score 0):

When you start to drag a node save a reference of that node.
When you drop that node use that reference.

Make container draggable.

Comment: Dose the vue binding remain ?

Comment: deends on how you implement it, basically you can choose what data you store/ reference - but its basically this schema